# How do I make strings and variables editable and printing them? (Python)

Tags: python

Yes I know that this is very much to ask, and I'm sorry, but I usually learn the best by doing stuff instead of reading stuff.

So I would like to for example set a variable to 1995 and a string to John
and then when I open the python file, I would be able to see the name of the string and variable and change them, like this.

**python file:**

```
Name  John
Year  1995
set year 2005
show options
Name John
Year 1995
```

And when I'm done I would like to print all strings and variables to a text file. You don't have to teach me like a baby, just tell me where I can find this information?

Comment: Learn by doing a tutorial like [python the hard way](https://learnpythonthehardway.org). This whole question sounds like a lazy kop out tbh.

Comment: Try Google. I hear it usually will take you where you want

Comment: How did you *not* get this information?  Searching for "Python introduction" or "Python tutorial" will get you there.  What did you use?

Answer (score 0):

for learn you should read python reference:

https://www.python.org/

but :

in python create variable is very easy

```
year = 1995
```

and then :

```
year = input("Enter Year:")
print(year)
```

if you want save your data in file , you can use this method:

```
my_result = open("myfile.txt","a")
my_result.write(year)
```

And all these can have different method in python